# Tomcat 6, DB2 JNDI Datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, db2

we are using a *JDNI Datasource* with DB2 Driver in combination with a Tomcat 6.
The application use Hibernate and Spring Data JPA.

The problem is, that the *HotDeployment* (with RPM) fails.
After a *HotDeployment* we get the following error in the log:

> Information: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load DB2JccConfiguration.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

And the application fails to start...

Definition in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/theDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testDS" auth="Container"    
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
maxActive="10" minIdle="2" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="120000"   
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000" 
username="xxx" password="xxx"
driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
url="jdbc:db2://xxxx;"
validationQuery="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1" />
```

And the Bean definition in the spring config class:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

        DataSource dataSource = null;

        try {
            final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup =
            new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
            dataSource = 
            dsLookup.getDataSource(JNDI_DATASOURCE_BASE_NAME + 
           this.jndiDataSourceLookupName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
            throw ex;
        }

        return dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I changed to tomcat7 and replaced  "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" with the factory from tomcat. After this changes the problem was solved.